# What do the asterisks mean in the Y-DNA Standard Y-STR values table on Family Tree DNA?

Tags: dna, y-dna, familytreedna.com

In my yDNA results on FamilyTreeDNA.com there are two asterisks on DYS19 and three on DYS389II as shown in this image:

[image]

What do these mean?  I do not see any legend.  Does it have to do with how quickly they mutate?  I tested yDNA-111 and none of the other entries have these asterisks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [FTDNA help pages](https://www.familytreedna.com/learn/user-guide/y-dna-myftdna/y-str-results-page/) are the following notes:

> ** DYS19 is also known as DYS394.
>   *** The Family Tree DNA and the Genographic Project report DYS389II differently.

So the asterisks are just footnotes on STR nomenclature, nothing to do with how quickly they mutate. However this information may be important if you are comparing these STR results from multiple testing companies.